# Is it possible to load a file into an app from another app?

Tags: android

I'm interested in writing a generic frontend app for Android. I'm thinking along the lines of a media center like XBMC.

This frontend app would (hopefully) be able to read files on a sd card and load those files into a 2nd app (which it would then launch).

Ideally - I would like the frontend to lie dormant once the 2nd app is launched. I would then like some tiny, low-overhead listener app to run in the background and wait for a specific button press (probably the back button). Said button press would then close the 2nd app and force the frontend app to appear again in place of it.

Has anyone tried anything like this? Some code snippets or tutorial links would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You can't listen for the back button (or any other button for that matter) press from anything in the background. But the behavior that you describe is the way it would work by default under the Android system if you call startActivity from the first app to start the second, and then the user presses back it will go back to whatever was below that on the ActivityStack, which will be your first application.

Comment: As FoamyGuy says, your goal is approximately the same as normal android behavior.  Read up on Intents and how you can use them to hand off a file to a player/viewer application.

Comment: Thank you both. So what about the first part of my question? Is it possible to files into the 2nd application as well? Or would this functionality vary amongst applications?